# Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, email

Good morning,

Today I have found something wrong in my website when I try to send an e-mail trough the mail() PHP function. The mail is not sent and I have this error message:

```
Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/user/html/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(18) : eval()'d code on line 57
```

What can I do in order to know which is the problem in this module? I have to enable the mail() function somewhere in my Joomla 3.3?

And that's my line 57:

```
mail('mymail@mail.com','Contact from',$message,$headers);
```

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: Are you using some sort of hosting service or are you the administrator of your own server?

Comment: You could connect to the mail server directly and use SMTP to send the mail =) If sockets are allowed, which I doubt. And it's a lot of hard work.

Comment: That's a server warning. You need to speak to your hosts about it.

Comment: I'm not the administrator of the hosting, but I can contact them. They are going to resolve this problem? Thanks, Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that whatever host you're using has disabled `mail()`. Note that `mail()` can be used to send out mass spam, for example:

```
while(true) {
    mail('mymail@mail.com','Contact from',$message,$headers);
}
```

A lot of shared hosts throttle `mail()` or outright disable it. You'll have to contact your hosting provider about the issue.

Comment: Thanks Geoff.
I have read some other posts and they say that I can use PHPMailerClass. With that PHPMailer I will be able to send mails with that function disabled? Thanks, Regards.

Comment: @wiraj Likely not, if PHPMailer is using the `mail` function.