# php mail function authentication

Tags: php, email

I have found something wrong in my website when I try to send an e-mail through the `mail()` function. The mail is not sent and I have this error message:

> PHP Warning:  mail() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/natureex/public_html/mail/contact_me.php on line 24

This is my code:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) ||  empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'geral@aaa.pt'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: info@aaa.pt\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

The line 24 is this one:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

I have contact my host and they said this:

> Please be informed that, for security reasons, all email submissions
>   via PHPmailer must be authenticated. If you want to send e-mail via
>   PHP, you must have an e-mail account associated with it.

Comment: I think the error and the message from your host are self-explanatory.

Comment: Search for "php mail authentication".

Comment: I'm not sure if your host thinks you're using phpmailer or is recommending that you should. Either way you'll need to authenticate with a mail server, most likely with your host's SMTP server.

Comment: [Link one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257048/3578036), [link two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603363/3578036).